# why doesn't padding have any effect

Tags: css

This is a css-noob question, but I don't get it: Why doesn't the following code show any padding for the outer div?

```
<html>
    <style>
        div {
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding:10em 30em 10em 30em;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        a {
        font-size:1rem; 
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <div>
            <a href="#">hello</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you remove the font-size property you'll see the padding. But why does font-size influence the padding at all??

Comment: I suspect it is because you specified 0 as the font size initially and then REM the child, which I didn't think would work with font 0...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the padding in `em` units which is calculated based on a base font size of the element that it's being applied on, you have set the font size to `0px`, so the calculated output for the `em` unit is 0 (let's say 10em x 0(px)), so the padding gets a size of `0`.

You can use `rem` instead of `em`. `rem` is based on the document's `root` or `HTML` tag's font size. So if you need to use `em` but the enforced font size on the element is not proper, set a root font size on the `HTML` tag and whenever needed use `rem` instead of `em`.

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. I am dealing with an external framework with does indeed set the font-size to 0, so I was stuck with the design. Everything  I did had no effect, but this clarifies everything. Setting the padding to px helps. Very helpful answer, for me at least.

Comment: I have tried to switch to the rem unit, which in this case looks to respect the padding. When would you recommend to use rem instead of em?

Answer (score 1):

"The em and ex units depend on the font and may be different for each element in the document. The em is simply the font size".

source: [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

So... 0 font-size is 0 padding when `em` is used for padding.

Comment: @13ruce1337 I'm surprised you are surprised. Perhaps you are thinking of w3schools... not w3.org.

Comment: I had a few drinks. You are correct. I will be leaving now :D

Comment: Ha! Don't drink and SO... oh wait, I do that all the time.